# Deadlocks in PostgreSQL when running a simple UPDATE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, postgresql-9.5, database-deadlocks

`update cities set cdb_data = NULL, updated_at = now() where cities.id = 1;`

We loop through cities and update cities with cdb_data as a part of rails code, however we keep getting the below error.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::TRDeadlockDetected: ERROR:  deadlock detected
DETAIL:  Process 26741 waits for ShareLock on transaction 2970537161; blocked by process 26818.
Process 26818 waits for ShareLock on transaction 2970537053; blocked by process 26741.
HINT:  See server log for query details.
CONTEXT:  while updating tuple (39,15) in relation "cities"
UPDATE "cities" SET "cdb_data" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "cities"."id" = $3
```

Ruby code that updates the city object

```
    city              = City.find_or_create_by(uuid: city_data['uuid'])
    city.name         = city_data['name']
    city.state_id     = city_data['state_id']
    city.cdb_data     = city_data
    city.save
```

I am clueless about to which record this error is happening and why?
Even with the production dump on local or in staging, this doesn't seem to happen.
Any help would be much appreciated.

I am running the server on `heroku` so I am not really sure I could see the postgres logs.

Comment: Can you give more details on how you're updating the records? Are you fetching multiple records, getting lock on them, and updating one by one? Will need more details on that.

Comment: Have updated the question with the ruby script that is updating the city

Comment: I am fetching the record one by one and updating the record.

Comment: Still not clear. Where and when is the transaction started and committed? Try to figure out, if you're updating multiple records from 2 different transactions, in different order? Interleaving updates across 2 transaction might be causing this issue.

Comment: For e.g.: Tx 1 is updating city in order -> `1, 4, 6, 8`. While Tx 2 is updating in order -> `4, 6, 8, 1`. Now, Tx 1 might be taking lock on record `1`, and Tx 2 would have taken lock on record `4`. So, `Tx 1` can't proceed, untill `Tx 2` finishes. But `Tx 2` has to wait on lock release on record `1`, which is held by `Tx 1`, hence deadlock.

Comment: I am updating multiple records sequentially one after the another in the same transaction. Can DeadLock happen then too?

Comment: Again, can't really know which query is waiting on locks, without looking at more code. May be, try to look into `SELECT * FROM pg_locks WHERE not granted` table, may be that can help.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM pg_locks WHERE not granted` this query gives zero rows.

Comment: But it seems illogical no.
I am looping through a json data and then `finding_or_creating` and `updating` citiy.
How can there possibly be deadlock in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find what is locking the update query, one could use

```sql
SELECT pg_blocking_pids(<pid of the query that is locked>);
```

Answer (score 2):

Two such transactions can easily deadlock.

To avoid that problem make sure that when you “loop through the cities”, you always do so in the same order, using something like:

```
FOR c IN
   SELECT * FROM city
   WHERE /* whatever */
   ORDER BY city.id
LOOP
   /* perform the update */
END LOOP;
```